# Request Google cloud speech-to-text API gives 503 error?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I ran the following python sample code on this page (you need a private key to run this): https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries

```py
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import speech
import os

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'key.json'

# Instantiates a client
client = speech.SpeechClient()

# The name of the audio file to transcribe
gcs_uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/speech/brooklyn_bridge.raw"

audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)

config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=16000,
    language_code="en-US",
)

# Detects speech in the audio file
response = client.recognize(config=config, audio=audio)

for result in response.results:
    print("Transcript: {}".format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
```

This results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\98274\anaconda3\envs\carla\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\98274\anaconda3\envs\carla\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 826, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "C:\Users\98274\anaconda3\envs\carla\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 729, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1614347442.192000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":4090,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1614347442.192000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":394,"grpc_status":14}]}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\98274\anaconda3\envs\carla\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 184, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "C:\Users\98274\anaconda3\envs\carla\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 failed to connect to all addresses

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/98274/Desktop/carla_ppo/test_connection.py", line 22, in <module>
    response = client.recognize(config=config, audio=audio)
  File "C:\Users\98274\anaconda3\envs\carla\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\speech_v1\services\speech\client.py", line 334, in recognize
    response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
  File "C:\Users\98274\anaconda3\envs\carla\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 145, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\98274\anaconda3\envs\carla\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 286, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "C:\Users\98274\anaconda3\envs\carla\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 206, in retry_target
    last_exc,
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.RetryError: Deadline of 120.0s exceeded while calling functools.partial(<function _wrap_unary_errors.<locals>.error_remapped_callable at 0x0000026B56606A68>, config {
  encoding: LINEAR16
  sample_rate_hertz: 16000
  language_code: "en-US"
}
audio {
  uri: "gs://cloud-samples-data/speech/brooklyn_bridge.raw"
}
, metadata=[('x-goog-api-client', 'gl-python/3.7.9 grpc/1.31.0 gax/1.23.0 gapic/2.0.1')]), last exception: 503 failed to connect to all addresses
```

What's the problem? Does it related to internet issue because I am in China? How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you let me know more details? For example, which language did you use?

Comment: Please read this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @rmesteves I use python. I posted more details in the description.

Comment: I was able to run the code provided in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries) without any issues. Could you try to run in Cloud Shell? Also, it seems you can not connect to the API from your machine, do you have any firewall rules?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes I solved it. Yes, it is firewall issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting the answer as CommunityWiki to further contribuite to the community.

As discussed in the comment section, the code provided in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries) is running smoothly. However, you have to make sure that you set your credentials using `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` so your request is authenticated. Also,the client libraries have to be properly installed.

In @antaressgzz case's the request to the API was being blocked by a firewall rule. Thus, it is a good practice to check these rules, changing them if applicable.

Comment: @antaressgzz, I posted the answer as Community Wiki and I would appreciate if you could accept and upvote it.